# Marker CustomInfoWindow Imageview overrides all other images

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, infowindow

I'm trying to do a map with some markers, which should have an infolabel with an image and textview. I already solved that the text of every infolabel is different but i'm struggling with the imageview.

When I add a new marker my app takes the new image an puts it in every infowindow that exists...

Here is my codesnippet where i set the value of the image- and textview:

```
public class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    private Activity context;

    public CustomInfoWindowAdapter(Activity context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        boolean imageGeandert = false;
        View view = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_infowindow, null);

        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
        TextView tvSubTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.addressTxt);


        tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
        tvSubTitle.setText(marker.getSnippet());

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.clientPic);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.logo);
            Log.d("Loka2", String.valueOf(MapsActivity.iconFinalFinal2));


        return view;
    }

}
```

The Log.d Output looks like this:

*12-19 21:36:14.499 25315-25315/com.example.yannick.mapdemo D/Lokale Bitmap: android.graphics.Bitmap@9bb0b83

12-19 21:36:14.526 25315-25315/com.example.yannick.mapdemo D/Loka2: android.graphics.Bitmap@9bb0b83

12-19 21:36:14.672 25315-25315/com.example.yannick.mapdemo D/Lokale Bitmap: android.graphics.Bitmap@40daa30

12-19 21:36:14.682 25315-25315/com.example.yannick.mapdemo D/Loka2: android.graphics.Bitmap@40daa30

12-19 21:36:14.844 25315-25315/com.example.yannick.mapdemo D/Lokale Bitmap: android.graphics.Bitmap@4fa0090

12-19 21:36:14.854 25315-25315/com.example.yannick.mapdemo D/Loka2: android.graphics.Bitmap@4fa0090

12-19 21:36:14.948 25315-25315/com.example.yannick.mapdemo D/Loka2: android.graphics.Bitmap@4fa0090

12-19 21:36:15.014 25315-25315/com.example.yannick.mapdemo D/Loka2: android.graphics.Bitmap@4fa0090

12-19 21:36:15.062 25315-25315/com.example.yannick.mapdemo D/Loka2: android.graphics.Bitmap@4fa0090*

The last one is taken for every existing infowindow and I dont know why....

Comment: You just need to map each Marker to an image ID, and use this map in order to determine what image resource to use in `getInfoContents()`.  You could use a `HashMap<Marker, Integer>`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, can you give me a short example how this is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to map each Marker to an image ID, and use this map in order to determine what image resource to use in `getInfoContents()`.

First, define the map as an instance variable:

```
Map<Marker, Integer> mMarkerMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Then populate this map whenever a Marker is added to the map:

```
public void addMarker(LatLng latLng, String title, String snippet, int imageID) {

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
        .position(latLng)
        .title(title)
        .snippet(snippet);
    Marker marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    mMarkerMap.put(marker, imageID);
}
```

You can call the method above like this:

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(37.7244502,-122.4703867);
String title = "title";
String snippet = "snippet";
addMarker(latLng, title, snippet, R.mipmap.logo);
```

Then modify your InfoWindowAdapter in order to use the corresponding resource for the InfoWindow of a specific Marker:

```
public class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    private Activity context;

    public CustomInfoWindowAdapter(Activity context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        boolean imageGeandert = false;
        View view = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_infowindow, null);

        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
        TextView tvSubTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.addressTxt);

        tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
        tvSubTitle.setText(marker.getSnippet());

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.clientPic);

        //get resource ID and set as image resource:
        int resID =  mMarkerMap.get(marker);
        imageView.setImageResource(resID);

        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your help but in CustomWindowInfoAdapter I get: "Cannot resolve to symbol mMarkerMap"